# FragmentStateAdapter is not calling createfragment function when fragment changes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a slight issue with the createFragment method in FragmentStateAdapter. I would expect that createFragment is called every time when fragment changes in ViewPager2. However, the createFragment is called only when the first fragment change occurs. Then the createFragment method is never called again.

My code:

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                myTextView.setText("0");
                return discover_page;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                myTextView.setText("1");
                return top_page;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                myTextView.setText("2");
                return friends_page;
            }
            default: return null;
        }
    }
```

In this code, the myTextView is set to "2" when the first fragment change occurs and never becomes anything else, even when fragments are being changed. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because fragments are not (re)created all the time. They're created and then reused. In order to have your textview change text appropriatelly, you need to use [OnPageChangeCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback)

Something like this:

```
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);

            //your code
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    myTextView.setText("0");
                    //return discover_page;
                }
                case 1:
                {
                    myTextView.setText("1");
                    //return top_page;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    myTextView.setText("2");
                    //return friends_page;
                }
                //default: return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    });
```